# Personal folder does not show all messages in it

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm lately encountering a verry strange problem in Outlook 2013 where my personal folders (local PST file) are not showing all messages that are stored in them.

I use these folders as a sort of local archive by manually moving messages into them.

But for some reason not all messages that I have moved into them are being shown. I can find such messages using advanced search. It even showns in search results that the messages are stored in the same local folder that doesen't show them.

I have checked to make sure no filter is applied to these local folders but still not all messages are shown in them.

I even tried resetting all views by starting outlok with `/clearviews` parameter and nothing has changed.

So what else can I do?

PS: It seems I'm encountering problem only in folders that are stored in one PST file (the one I created this year) but I'm not encountering such problem with local folders from other PST files (for previous years)

Comment: How big are those pst files? Does this affect random emails, or is there a pattern (like only the oldest ones don't show). Also, do you use conversation grouping?

Comment: The newest PST file that is showing this issue is less than 50 MB in size. But older ones who are not exhibiting these issues are around 1 GB in size each. And currently I have 14 of them connected. Do you think Outlook might be running out of memory for storing index? And no I'm not using conversation grouping. As for the pattern I can't recognize any. The issue occurred during the day where few of the personal folders just no longer showed any mails. But if I moved another one to that folder it remained visible. ...

Comment: ... As I already mentioned when I performed an advanced search for finding the lost e-mails using current year as arrival date result contained all e-mails even those that are not visible in personal folders despite the fact that search results clearly stated that those e-mails are stored in the troublesome personal folder.

Comment: Today I managed to get all emails from one personal folders to become visible by dragging them again to it from the above mentioned search results. But I will have to wait till tomorrow to se whether they remain visible or will they disappear again